# What are some good sources for learning how to implement credit card processing on my PHP designed website?

Tags: php, shopping-cart, credit-card

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is a good tutorial or book to learn credit card processing using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1938714/what-is-a-good-tutorial-or-book-to-learn-credit-card-processing-using-php)

I use PHP, MySQL, Javascript, and HTML5 on my website, and I want to set up a shopping cart and accept credit card payments. I want to develop my own system, as opposed to buying a pre-made shopping cart app. I've never done this before and I have no idea where to begin. Any suggestions?

Comment: Read the documentation of the credit card processor of your choice.

Comment: Don't re-invent the wheel, as developing such a system correctly requires a lot of knowledge in regards to web application security and PCI DSS. Get an already vouched for system that has a proven track record in protecting the information it will handle.

Answer (score 0):

Each credit card processor implements it's own API. You need to read their documentation and write code to work with their API. Many of them come with client libraries you can use to get you started.

I would advise against attempting to store credit card numbers, then you need to be PCI compliant which is a big effort.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just starting to integrate an Payment gateway, i suggest you try **PayPal** Credit card using Direct Pay 
https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_dcc_hub-outside.
They provide their own sandbox account, several supporting API & Libraries and so many documentation to get you through.